# How to copy certain files from remote to local?

Tags: shell, scp

I can copy all files with extension .ds from a subdirectory "folder" to my local using:

```
scp -r  name@host:/data/folder/*.ds /pathtodestination/
```

However, there are lots of subdirectories under `data` and I want to copy all/only files with .ds from all subdirectories under `data` to my local.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What shell are you using? While it is probably bash, the information is crucial, as the posted answer shows.

Comment: Also, do you have return access from `host`. I.e., can you `ssh` over to `host`, run `find -name '*.ds' -exec scp '{}' name@local:/path/to/destination`?

Comment: Use `rsync` for these more complicated patterns. SCP is suitable only for simple tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to try this

```
scp -r  name@host:/data/**/*.ds /pathtodestination/
```

OR

```
find <start directory> -iname "<all my files type>" -exec cp {} <target_dir> \;
```